# Pseudocode notation

Tags: pseudocode

In pseudocode, how do you state comparisons and statements? Should I use `==` and `=` like in programming languages or should I completely switch to `$=$` for comparison and `$:=$` for each statement? What else do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:=` for assignments might be a little less prone to confusion but either convention should be acceptable, so long as you are consistent. If the audience is theoretical CS people then I would use `:=` for assignments and `=` for comparison. If your audience is programming students with little theoretical background, the convention of the language they are used to might be the most understandable.

I've seen recent papers on the arXiv use both conventions.